# Postgresql 9.1 on ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I have a quick question. Did you install postgresql 9.1 on the ubuntu server 9.10 ?
If yes, it was a pure installation or update from 8.4 ? If update how did it go ?
Where did you get deb package ?
Oh, really, I need deb package because install from sources on a lot of server isn't good idea.

Comment: Martin Pitt's PPA doesn't contain a release for Karmic (9.10) as it's just too old. See : https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql . You might be able to get the source packages for Lucid and rebuild them for Karmic though. All in all, the idea of "I don't want to build from source, but I'm happy to run some random backport binaries for an ancient Ubuntu release" smacks somewhat of http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#A_bug_I.27m_encountering_is_fixed_in_a_newer_minor_release_of_PostgreSQL.2C_but_I_don.27t_want_to_upgrade._Can_I_get_a_patch_for_just_this_issue.3F

Comment: BTW, Karmic isn't an LTS release and it's well past end-of-life (April 2011). It's unlikely you'll see many people interested in maintaining packages for it when there was an LTS release immediately following it.

Answer (score 1):

Your choices in this situation are limited:

1. Find someone who has already compiled a `.deb` package for your version of Ubuntu
   (As far as I'm aware that's not possible for something as old as Karmic (9.10))
2. Build/Install from source on each server
3. Build from source and assemble a `.deb` package to install on your servers.
   (Probably the most viable option if you have lots of systems & can't upgrade the OS.)

In any case you will need to observe the [Postgres upgrade procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/upgrading.html) - you can't just dump the new DB binaries on your server and expect it to work with the old `PGDATA` format.

---

As Craig pointed out Karmic Koala (Ubuntu 9.10) is well past end of life -- you should really be considering an upgrade path to a supported OS (I'm not even sure Postgres will build, or that your system libraries don't have bugs that will cause Postgres to behave badly if it does compile) - If you ask a question about upgrade paths (describing your environment with enough detail) we can probably help you get onto more stable ground.